# Laravel set $fillable via trait using database columns

Tags: php, laravel, traits

I'm trying to create a trait that will automatically set `$fillable` based on the model table schema:

```
trait DynamicFillable
{
    public static function bootDynamicFillableTrait()
    {
        static::retrieved(function (Model $model) {
            $model->fillable(Schema::getColumnListing($model->getTable()));
        });
    }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
static::retrieved(function (Model $model) {
    $model->fillable = Schema::getColumnListing($model->getTable());
});
```

Which doesn't work either, because `$fillable` is protected.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it:

```
trait DynamicFillable
{
    public function getFillable()
    {
        return Schema::getColumnListing($this->getTable());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

im just wondering, if you plan to make all fields on your table to be fillable, why running into problem creating a code for it?

can you just put:

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

on your model?

just a thought.

Comment: Because if you pass a value whose key does not exist as a column in the database you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this is an old question, but for those googling this problem in the future;

As @stardust4891 pointed out, you can override the `getFillable()` function within the trait. However, this might make your trait not play nicely with other traits or customisations you make.

Instead, you can utilise [trait intialization](https://medium.com/swlh/laravel-booting-and-initializing-models-with-traits-2f77059b1915). within your trait you could do the following:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models\Traits;

trait AddToFillableExample
{
    
    /**
     * Initialize the trait
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function initializeAddToFillableExample()
    {
        $this->fillable[] = 'my_custom_field';
    }
}
```